# How to control the screenshots of my website in the recently used websites list shown on the new tab in my browser

Tags: html, firefox, screenshot, thumbnails, browser-cache

Browser like Firefox and Chrome take screen shot of the visited websites and can show them on a new tab as "recent used website".

Since my website is showing confidential information, how could I avoid the browsers to take screen shots for the "recent website" list, or at least limit it to the login page (like Facebook or banking website are doing)?

I found a possible answer in [Is there a W3C standard meta tag to determine the cover image used to represent a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463059/is-there-a-w3c-standard-meta-tag-to-determine-the-cover-image-used-to-represent) but it seems a still unstable method, and banking sites I investigated are not using it apparently so I suspect there is another (better?) solution.

Any idea? I need it working at least for Firefox.

Note: sites are using HTTPS. Under Chrome, use HTTPS seems to solve it since blank screen is shown as preview. Firefox does show it even when using HTTPS.

**UPDATE:**
On Mozzila's support page https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thumbnails-new-tab-page-missing-how-get-them-back they state the following:

> Note: Some websites don't allow images (--> thumbnail) to be generated and saved

Unfortunately they don't tell how to do it... But yes it seems there is a way to avoid it...

**UPDATE 2:**
What I actually am looking for is that the site uses cache for Javascript and images, but not for thumbnails. Use of HTTPS would to solve it, except because of the Firefox bug.

Comment: Ha! Good question. I bet the answer will be different for each browser, though, and it's possible this can't be prevented at all.

Comment: Banking sites and Facebook are doing it, so it's feasible... Browser specific is not a major issue since browser can be detected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I finally **got it solved.**

First of all, the "application manifest" does not help.

Based on @Peter's answer I found a way to implement it without loosing the browser cache for my "usefull" code, and keeping URL intact.

To archive it, I use a "main" page, that is the actual URL for the browser (-->thumbnail), with no caching, but it just contains a frame, where my "real" page is called internally. The real page does use caching, but since the website URL is the "no cache page", it seems thumbnail is not always the login page, even when the new page tab thumbnail points to my "main" page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache no-store">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<title>My Website</title>
</head><body style="margin: 0;">
 <iframe src="init_index_main.jsp" name="main"  style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

So actually I implement all 3 recommendations of Peter, avoiding their side effect. Actually, I was already using the frame workaround to hide the real URL to the (common) users.

Of course if the user opens a link in a new tab, leaving the "main" frame, it could generate a thumbnail, but that's no the normal flow so I can live with it.

Comment: Good work around :-) I like it! But yeah, Mozilla should fix it!

Answer (score 7):

**1. Turn Off Cache**

Perhaps you could set the [cache-control header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Avoiding_caching). This would tell the browser to make all possible efforts not to save the page on the user's computer. Sadly, this would be a performance hit since the user would need to pull down each page entirely for every call they make.

**2. HTTPS**

Browsers understand that https sites need more security, so won't include https sites in the speed dial page. You should file a report with [Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org).

**3. Unique URL**

Give the page with the sensitive information a unique URL every time it's opened.

Comment: Thank you Peter. But 1 & 3 are not feasible for my app. 2: there are already various open bugs for this. Unfortunately

Comment: But looking at my banking websites, it seems they use the NO CACHE option. <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"> <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">.

Comment: Interesting related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers

Comment: you did not explain *why* 1 is not feasible for you. if you don't provide information nobody can help you

Comment: Option 1 is feasible, but the no cache is not limited to the thumbnail. See my answer on how to use it limiting it to the thumbnails

Answer (score 3):

[Some browsers are sending a special header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2030947/199048) when creating the thumbnails

```
HTTP_X_PURPOSE  preview
```

But as far as I know Firefox takes the screenshot during normal browsing.

Comment: Will investigate and testi. Thanks. Will let you know my findings.

Comment: HTTP_X_PURPOSE is only a way to distinguish the two types of request: in the current version of Safari 4 (4.0.4) the Top Sites request for the base page (but not its JS/CSS/image resources) carries an additional HTTP header, namely “X-Purpose: preview“. Does not help in my case, More info on HTTP_X_PURPOSE here: https://sunpig.com/martin/2010/01/08/how-to-detect-a-page-request-from-safari-4s-top-sites-feature/

Answer (score 3):

Firefox's built-in thumbnail service [does not persist thumbs](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/62db1c9021cfbde9fa5e6e9601de16c21f4c7ce4/toolkit/components/thumbnails/PageThumbUtils.jsm#322-325) if the `Cache-Control: no-store` header is present. It may still render them at runtime, e.g. for aero peek, but they will not be saved to disk.

Private browsing mode also disables thumbnail rendering.

Comment: he did not provide a source linking that generic header - which generally refers to caching - to thumbnails